# Pipelining with bypassing

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

I am trying to understand the concept of bypassing by reading the following slide[image]

Bypassing is reading a value from an intermediate source. What does the arrow stand for?, does it mean that X is executed after M in the sequence?. How does it work?

Comment: I believe the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or (less so) [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange sites would be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: there exists a cpu-architecture tag and I have seen a lot of threads about cpu architecture.

Comment: This is asking about a concept in processors rather than a code or programming issue, which why I thought the Computer Science site (which specifically lists ["computer architecture" as on-topic](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) would get better answers.  I could be wrong, though, and I suppose it being "more on-topic on that site" does not necessarily mean "off-topic on this site".

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5):

Bypassing means the data at that stage is passed to the stage required. For example in the first case (MX bypass),
the output of the operation `ADD r2, r3` is available at the `M` stage, but has not written back to its destination `r1`. The `SUB` instruction is expecting one of its data to be available at `r1`. Since this `r1` data is produced by the `ADD` and "we" know that it is this same `r1` is needed for `SUB` we dont need to wait until the writeback stage `W` of `ADD` is complete. "We" can simply bypass the data to the `SUB` instruction.  The same goes with WX bypass as well.

Comment: Is *bypassing* the same as *data forwarding*?

Comment: Yes. In this context.